# How to pass array element to "use:" directive?

Tags: svelte

I'm creating multiple popper actions like this for each element which I want to have a popup

```js
$: {
        popperData = labeledText.map((el) => {
            const [popperRef, popperContent] = createPopperActions({
                placement: 'top-end',
                strategy: 'fixed'
            });
            return { popperRef, popperContent };
        });
}
```

but then how can I pass those references inside array to components?

```js
    {#each labeledText as { text, chunk_i }, i}
                <span
                    use:popperData[i].popperRef
```

above does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably declare [a const](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-const) for it:

```html
{#each ...
  {@const popper = popperData[i].popperRef}
    <span use:popper >...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Array map:

```html
// mapper must be a function to use the array map "this" argument
// to be clear: an arrow function does not have a "this"

function mapper({text, chunk_0}, idx)  {
  return {text, chunk_0, this[idx].popperRef}
}

// use "this" arg to pass popperData to the mapper    
{#each labeledText.map(mapper, popperData) as { text, chunk_i, popperRef }, i}
                        <span
                            use:action={popperRef}
```